# How to create a segue on condition

Tags: ios, swift, authentication

I have a login page backed up by Parse. I want to know how to create a segue only if the login has been confirmed through the Parse database, and then direct the user to a new View Controller.

This is the code for the login button:

```
@IBAction func logginginAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    var username = self.usernameField.text
    var password = self.passwordField.text

    if (count(username.utf16) < 4 || count(password.utf16) < 5 ) {

       var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Invalid", message: "Username/Password is too short!!", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()
    }
    else {
        self.actInd.startAnimating()

        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username, password: password, block: { (user, error) ->
            Void in

            self.actInd.stopAnimating()

            if ((user) != nil) {

            }else {
                var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Invalid", message: "Please recheck the information you just entered", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()

            }
        })
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is simple.

Connect your button to an IBAction, not directly to a segue.

Connect your segue from the view controller, not from the button. Give it a unique identifier.

In your IBAction method check the conditions you want to check, and if they are met, invoke your segue using `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`

Comment: Thank you! 

I have done this but when the login is confirmed, there is no transition to the segue to the new view controller. 

I added the "performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:" in the second if statement.